# How to find a file recursively in Java?

Tags: java, recursion

I am wondering how I would write a recursive program to locate a file in Java that is indicated by a starting path. It should search through a tree for a specified file. If the file is found, the location of the file should be returned. This is what I have so far (not much and still needs basic cleaning up). I need to use these exact methods. I'm mostly confused with what goes in what methods. So I know I need to use:

```
File f = new File(dirName);

String [] fileList = f.list();

File aFile = new File (dirName + "\\" + fileList[i]);

if (aFile.isDirectory()) {...}

public class FindFile {
```

If you could help me figure out what method each of those goes in that would be an amazing help!!! I'm just not really understanding the logic of each method. I also have a driver in another class that I need to utilize.

```
/**
 * This constructor accepts the maximum number of files to find.
 */
public FindFile (int maxFiles)
{
}

/**
 * The parameters are the target file name to look for and the directory to start in.
 * @param  target = target file name, dirName = directory to start in
 */
public void directorySearch (String target, String dirName) {
    File f = new File(dirName);
    String [] fileList = f.list();
    File aFile = new File(dirName + "\\" + fileList[i]);
    if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
    }
    else {
    }
}

/**
 * This accessor returns the number of matching files found.
 * @return number of matching files found
 */
public int getCount () {
    return -1;
}

/**
 * This getter returns the array of file locations, up to maxFiles in size.
 * @return array of file locations
 */
public String [] getFiles () {
    return new String[] {""};
}

/**
 * Prompt the user for max number of files to look for, the directory to start in, and the file name.
 * Then, print out the list of found files with the full path name to the file (including starting
 * directory). In the event of an exception being thrown, driver catches it and provides an appropriate
 * message to the user.
 */
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the max number of files to look for?");
    System.out.println("What directory should we start in?");
    Systme.out.println("What is the file name?");
    }
```

}

Answer (score 26):

You can use java 8 lambda features like this

```
try (Stream<Path> walkStream = Files.walk(Paths.get("your search directory"))) {
    walkStream.filter(p -> p.toFile().isFile()).forEach(f -> {
        if (f.toString().endsWith("file to be searched")) {
            System.out.println(f + " found!");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use recursion to search the file in all the files, directories and sub directories

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean found = searchFile(new File("/tmp"), "10174");
    System.out.println(found);
}

private static boolean searchFile(File file, String search) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            boolean found = searchFile(f, search);
            if (found)
                return true;
        }
    } else {
        if (search.equals(file.getName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If the file needs to returned if found

```
static File searchFile(File file, String search) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] arr = file.listFiles();
        for (File f : arr) {
            File found = searchFile(f, search);
            if (found != null)
                return found;
        }
    } else {
        if (file.getName().equals(search)) {
            return file;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Should change it to return the found File (or null) instead of a boolean.

Comment: @Bill Yes, updated answer

Comment: Updated description.

Comment: @iloveprogramming updated answer is what you are looking for, did you try this? 1st program returns just Boolean, 2nd returns the File object itself, File has a method to return absolute path

Comment: So I want the driver to print out the list of found files with the full path name to the file, including the starting directory. And also return the number of matching files found.

Comment: @iloveprogramming You can do that with the code as is with the .getAbsolutePath() method on the File object. If you're looking for multiple files, you can modify the sample to collect the files in a list and return the list once done.